# ¿Alguien ha usado la librería basic player?

Tags: java

lo que pasa es que ya pude usar esta librería casi en su totalidad pero mi único problema es que como puedo hacer un processbar o un jslider que vaya a la par que la canción y que pueda atrasar o adelantar al minuto que yo quiera, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo tengo estos métodos.

```
  @Override
    public void opened(Object stream, Map properties) {


    }



double duracion;
    @Override
    public void progress(int bytesread, long microseconds, byte[] pcmdata,
  Map properties) {


    }

    @Override
    public void stateUpdated(BasicPlayerEvent bpe) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setController(BasicController bc) {

    }
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que este pueda realizar lo que comente? :) espero y alguien me pueda responder.

Comment: A groso modo debes hacer el trabajo en el método **progress*, según el tamaño del fichero que se está reproduciendo y los bytes que se han leido. Lo que sí te diría es que hagas la actualización del progress bar en un hilo aparte, la parte gui no suele actualizarse tal como a nosotros nos gustaría.

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo, si no es molestia :) por favor